# Is it possible to set a unique background color for the whole block that the first child in a nested collapsible list using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following nested list (I omit the other first level li's for convenience). The list is in a larger container box. I have a border-top on every ul element and a border-bottom on every li element. And the li elements have their paddings.

html:

```
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="collapsible active">
        <i class="fas"></i><a href="#"> Item 1 </a>
        <ul class="collapsible__content">
          <li>
            <a href="#"> Item 2 </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"> Item 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.menu {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  color: #cfc6dc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #61676b;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #61676b;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.menu .collapsible__content {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 1rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.menu li:hover,
.menu .active {
  background: var(--color-active);
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.menu .fas {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I want item 1 and its whole block to have a different background color when its container li element is active, but I don't want the other nested li elements to have the same color when they are expanded. And I want those other elements to have their block in a different color when they are under hover. I tried to set a different background color for the class "collapsible__content" and overwrite it in response of the hover effect. However, the very outside margin cannot be wiped out.

Is this achievable in CSS? (If not, Javascript code can also be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, specifically the `>` css operator, which will only target the first level of children.

Also added an example of the `:first-child` selector in case that's more what you're looking for.

For the second question, you can target it under the `collapsible__content` class.

```css
.menu {
  background: #dddddd;
  color: #cfc6dc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #61676b;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #61676b;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.menu .collapsible__content {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 1rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.menu .fas {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu .collapsible__content {
  background-color: #000;
}

.menu .collapsible__content li {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #cfc6dc;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover,
.menu > ul > li.active {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.collapsed { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="collapsible active">
      <i class="fas"></i><a href="#"> Item 1 </a>
      <ul class="collapsible__content">
        <li>
          <a href="#"> Item 1.2 </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> Item 1.3 </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="collapsible">
      <i class="fas"></i><a href="#"> Item 2 </a>
      <ul class="collapsible__content collapsed">
        <li>
          <a href="#"> Item 2.2 </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> Item 2.3 </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="collapsible">
      <i class="fas"></i><a href="#"> Item 3 </a>
      <ul class="collapsible__content">
        <li>
          <a href="#"> Item 3.2 </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> Item 3.3 </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben. This is my fault... I forgot to mention that the list is in a larger container box, and each li has its borders. And what I am doing is to set a color for each "block" that is active or under hover. Is this doable? (I re-editted my initial question.)

Comment: Have edited the answer per your new code. Still having a little trouble visualizing exactly the question, but hopefully this is a little closer

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you so much for going into so much details and helping me out. The problem seems to be that "li" and "ul" elements always light up together. So I wrapped every "li" separately in a div, and then it worked...

Comment: If you mean `<ul><div><li>...` be careful with that - it's technically not valid [since `ul` can only contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) "Zero or more <li>, <script> and <template> elements." It may render oddly/unexpectedly depending on browser. If you mean `<ul><li><div>...` that should be good to go 

Comment: That was a very helpful piece of advice. Just now I noticed that I made those mistakes. Then I corrected them, and it still seems to work. Thanks a lot!